# ASP.NET antiforgerytoken saying that the object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I followed an exercise we did in class and I do not know why but `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is giving me the error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

```
<form method="post" action="\Files\Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="id" />

    <label>Choose photo (,jpg\.png):</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you remove the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() does it work or it gives the exception as well?

Comment: Q: Is what you showed us a .cshtml file?  Is it the *entire* .cshtml, or did you "leave stuff out"?  Q: How is it getting invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your forgot to return object in your action.**
Because your view is calling property `@Model.Id`

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Id = 999;

        return View(test);
    }
```